# Custom UITextField in Collection View not showing

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

Having issues with adding this custom TexView into my collection view. I can add the color and console does print out (99999999) but my custom UItextview Does not show up.

```
class chatMessageCell: UICollectionViewCell {

let textView1: UITextView = {
    let tV = UITextView()
    tV.text = "sample text"
    tV.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18)
    tV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return tV
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    //Uncommentting this shows RED COLOR for each collectionView
    //backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    addSubview(textView1) //<----for some reason this is not showing

    textView1.centerYAnchor.constraintLessThanOrEqualToAnchor(self.centerYAnchor).active = true
    textView1.centerXAnchor.constraintLessThanOrEqualToAnchor(self.centerXAnchor).active = true
    textView1.heightAnchor.constraintLessThanOrEqualToAnchor(self.heightAnchor).active = true
    textView1.widthAnchor.constraintLessThanOrEqualToConstant(200).active = true

    print(9999999999999999) <----this does print confirming that block works
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

In my viewDidLoad for UICollectionView

```
class ChatLogController: UICollectionViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    collectionView!.registerClass(chatMessageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

    setupInPutComponent()
}
 override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messageS.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}

//make collectionview horizontal like TableView

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 80)
}
....
```

I am receiving no errors and the code makes sense. Not sure why I cant see the UITextview but can see the color when I uncomment backgroundColor. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is 0 a valid solution to all of your constraints?

Comment: Yes, I made sure to center everything for my constraints.

Comment: I solved the problem temporarily by using a label instead of a textView. Not sure why this works, but it does. For purposes that I am using the collectionView i think a Label should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constraints need to specify position and size of the view unambiguously (i.e. the solution has to be a set of concrete values). You achieve this either by allowing autolayout to use implicit constraints based on the view's content size (set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `true`) or by specifying concrete values yourself (use "equal" constraints instead of "less than or equal").

> I solved the problem temporarily by using a label instead of a textView

`UITextView` is a scroll container (it subclasses `UIScrollView`), so it does not have implicit content size while `UILabel` does.

Comment: OMG!! How did I make that mistake. I looked at this code 100X and missed this. Okay let me fix this. Wow.